# How to tell the source of an email memo

Tags: lotus-notes, email, lotusscript, lotus-formula

In Notes, an email memo may either have originated from inside the mailbox database/file in which it is found, i.e. composed by a user of the mailbox and then sent to an external or internal party, or the email memo may have originated from outside the mailbox.

Additionally, a mailbox may be a group mailbox, with multiple users, and we want to consider any email sent by any user from that mailbox to be an outgoing mail item, as well as an incoming mail item if it is also addressed to the mailbox.

Considering that any email may have been placed in any folder at any time, and that regardless of its current location (unless deleted completely) we want to know for each given email whether it is of internal or external origin, and at what time it was sent or arrived respectively, how can we tell using only the NotesDocument fields that Notes commonly uses with respect to incoming and/or outgoing memos, whether a given memo was received by the mailbox or was sent from the mailbox?

The goal is to create a view using Domino Designer that includes only incoming mail items or only outgoing mail items, regardless of their current folder.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and how that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@IsAvailable(DeliveredDate)` to recognize emails that were sent to a Notes mailbox.

If the DeliveredDate item does not exist, then you can use `@IsAvailable(PostedDate)` to recognize emails that were sent from a Notes mailbox.

If neither the DeliveredDate nor PostedDate item exist, then the email message is a draft that was never sent.

You can examine the value of the SentTo item to confirm whether the email message was actually sent to the mailbox that it is contained in. Just because it's there now, that doesn't mean it was actually delivered there!  Users can easily copy and paste messages from one mailbox file to another, and the various items that the message contain are not changed.

I don't believe that there is a definitive way to know if the email message was actually sent from the mailbox file that it is contained in. The From item normally reflects the name of the user who sent the email, not the mailbox the user was accessing when it was sent. Special programming for a group mailbox template might change that behavior, but you may not be able to count on it.

Comment: Doesn't the router task add PostedDate and DeliveredDate based on the information from the original email even if it's an external one?

Comment: If the router added a PostedDate item to inbound messages, they would appear in the Sent view because the selection formula for the Sent view looks like this:  SELECT DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView)).

Comment: As well as the From Field indicating the sender, the Principal Field should be considered when trying to calculate the sender